# dynamically create custom buttons in code wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

i have a button control in code as

```
Button>
                <Button.Content>

                        <StackPanel Orientation='Horizontal' >
                            <TextBlock Text='{Binding ramDay, Mode=TwoWay}' Margin='0,-18,0,0' Style='{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}'/>
                        <TextBlock Text='{Binding enDay, Mode=TwoWay}' Margin='15,10,0,0' Style='{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}'/>

                    </StackPanel>

                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
```

but i want to create as many buttons as user want with different values of textboxes as user want them. but i am unable to find any way, kindly help me.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `custom user control` in you project by using this code there. Thereafter in your mainPage in the code behind add the userControl dynamically to the grid present on the UI in a for-loop or any other method which you find suitable to your situation.